# Conditional values in a Pandas data frame based on dates

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have the following Pandas data frame:

```
import pandas as pd
df= pd.DataFrame({'type':['Asset','Liability','Asset','Liability','Asset'],'Amount':[10,-10,20,-20,5],'Maturity Date':['2018-01-22','2018-01-22','2018-06-22','2018-06-22','2019-01-22']})
```

Depending on user input, I wanted to modify the Pandas data frame to only show certain values. For a "date" of 2018-01-31, I would like the data frame to be:

```
df1= pd.DataFrame({'2018-01-31':[0,0,20,-20,5],'type':['Asset','Liability','Asset','Liability','Asset'],'Amount':[10,-10,20,-20,5],'Maturity Date':['2018-01-22','2018-01-22','2018-06-22','2018-06-22','2019-01-22']})
```

Similarly for a "date" of 2018-12-31, I would like the data frame to be:

```
df2= pd.DataFrame({'2018-12-31':[0,0,0,0,5],'2018-01-31':[0,0,20,-20,5],'type':['Asset','Liability','Asset','Liability','Asset'],'Amount':[10,-10,20,-20,5],'Maturity Date':['2018-01-22','2018-01-22','2018-06-22','2018-06-22','2019-01-22']})
```

Any suggestions for the most efficient way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

User input the date , then we can get it base on this

```
df['2018-12-31']=(df['Maturity Date']>pd.to_datetime('2018-12-31'))*df.Amount
df
Out[356]: 
   Amount Maturity Date       type  2018-12-31
0      10    2018-01-22      Asset           0
1     -10    2018-01-22  Liability           0
2      20    2018-06-22      Asset           0
3     -20    2018-06-22  Liability           0
4       5    2019-01-22      Asset           5
```

---

Another solution using *`np.where`* + *`df.insert`*

```
date = '2018-01-31'
df.insert(0, date, np.where(df['Maturity Date'] > '2018-01-31', df.Amount, 0))

df

   2018-01-31  Amount Maturity Date       type
0           0      10    2018-01-22      Asset
1           0     -10    2018-01-22  Liability
2          20      20    2018-06-22      Asset
3         -20     -20    2018-06-22  Liability
4           5       5    2019-01-22      Asset
```

Comment: Willing to bet this is the fastest one actually. Also, that was my last vote for the day.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ a ha , thank you ~ :-) also, np.where looks great !

Answer (score 1):

Let's use `assign` and `mask`:

```
print(df)

   Amount Maturity Date       type
0      10    2018-01-22      Asset
1     -10    2018-01-22  Liability
2      20    2018-06-22      Asset
3     -20    2018-06-22  Liability
4       5    2019-01-22      Asset
```

Add, first column,

```
input_date = '2018-01-31'
df = df.assign(input_date=df.Amount.mask(df["Maturity Date"] <= input_date,0)).rename(columns={'input_date':input_date})
print(df)

   Amount Maturity Date       type  2018-01-31
0      10    2018-01-22      Asset           0
1     -10    2018-01-22  Liability           0
2      20    2018-06-22      Asset          20
3     -20    2018-06-22  Liability         -20
4       5    2019-01-22      Asset           5
```

Add, second column,

```
input_date = '2018-12-31'
df = df.assign(input_date=df.Amount.mask(df["Maturity Date"] <= input_date,0)).rename(columns={'input_date':input_date})
print(df)

   Amount Maturity Date       type  2018-01-31  2018-12-31
0      10    2018-01-22      Asset           0           0
1     -10    2018-01-22  Liability           0           0
2      20    2018-06-22      Asset          20           0
3     -20    2018-06-22  Liability         -20           0
4       5    2019-01-22      Asset           5           5
```